# How to set environment variable from java code and use this variable without restarting my workspace

Tags: java, windows, cmd, environment-variables

I have a requirement where I need to run a command which needs an environment variable value to be present beforehand on Windows OS. I tried using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe","/c","setx","ENVVAR","somevalue");
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe","/c","COMMANDTHATUSEENVAR");
```

Though this ENVVAR is set but the next command when runs give the error the ENVAR is not set. Now when I restart my workspace and run above code it happily takes the ENVAR value. But the problem is I cannot restart my workspace every time. So is there any possible solution where I get to set the environment variable and also use that value without restarting my workspace.

Comment: What do you mean by restart your "workspace"?

Comment: I mean restarting my eclipse IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the environemnt block is copied from parent process to child process, but you can change the environment copy of the process you start.

```
public class EnvironmentTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "CMD.exe"
            , "/C"
            , "start \"\" cmd /c \"set e & pause\""
        );
        pb.environment().put("ENVVAR", "This is a test");
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

The `cmd` instance started inside the `ProcessBuilder` has the environment variable defined. To show it, this instance is starting another one (the `start "" cmd ...`) to show in screen the value in the variable.

Probably in your case you will need something like

```
public class EnvironmentTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "CMD.exe"
            , "/C"
            , "start \"\" \"COMMANDTHATUSEEN‌​VAR\""
        );
        pb.environment().put("ENVVAR", "This is a test");
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I set my ENVAR in the put() and then in the new process which has the copy of new environment variable , I will run the second command as given ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "CMD.exe"
            , "/C"
            , "start \"\" cmd /c \"set e & pause\""
        );
        pb.environment().put("ENVVAR", "This is a test");
        Process p = pb.start();  p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe","/c","COMMANDTHATUSEENVAR");

Comment: By the above way I could set the ENVAR but  it gives the error that ENVAR is not set.

Comment: @user3789902, no, If you create two differente processes, each one will have a different environment block. You need to start your process from the one with the variable defined.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the /V option, and try to built a **single** command, like the following [example](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-environment-variable-for-just-one-command-in-windows-cmd-exe):

```
cmd /V /C "set EDITOR=vim&& echo !EDITOR!"
```

So my suggestion: first build a string that does what you need on the command line. Then translate that into something that works with the Java ProcessBuilder.

Alternatively: you could create a simple batch script that takes the ENVAR value as *argument*; sets the ENVAR and then runs your tool.

In the end, your problem is that the ProcessBuilder will **fork** a new Process; so the "changes" that you make there are *not* visible when forking of another process later on. When you re-start your eclipse, that runs in a completely *new* process which sees those updates made by your first system call.